# getDownloadURL not working

Tags: google-earth-engine, download, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I try to download some data using getDownloadUrl (see below). Unfortunately, i always get the following message:

> Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load

Does anyone have an idea why this fails? I tried Export.image.toDrive as an alternative but this one fails too.

````
////// Get Sweden as ROI
var country = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
var sweden = country.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'France'))
var roi = sweden;
Map.addLayer(roi, {}, 'ROI')
Map.centerObject(roi)
/////// START SCRIPT

// // Load satellite images
var hansenImage = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015'); // latest version of Hansen forest layer
var mcd = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD64A1'); // MODIS Burned Area layer version 6
//print(mcd)

// // create forest  mask for 2000 -- very low tau
var tau = 30; // Calibration parameter: Forest threshold (defaults = 20)
var forestRoi = hansenImage.select('treecover2000').clip(roi) // Crop satellite image to region of interest
var forestMask = forestRoi.gt(tau); // this is forest area in 2000

// // update forest mask to 2015
var lossImage = hansenImage.select(['loss']);     
var gainImage = hansenImage.select(['gain']);
var forestMask2015 = forestMask.subtract(lossImage).add(gainImage);
//Map.addLayer(lossImage.mask(lossImage), {palette:'blue'},'loss'); Map.addLayer(gainImage.mask(gainImage), {palette:'red'},'gain')
var NewForestMask = ee.Image(forestMask2015.mask(forestMask2015))
Map.addLayer(NewForestMask, {palette:'green'}, 'Forest Mask 2015')

// // Calculate the total forest area
var forestarea=NewForestMask.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());
var forest_region=forestarea.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),geometry: roi,scale: 500, maxPixels: 5e9});
print('Total forest area in 2015 (m2): ',forest_region) 

// // Constrain MCD image to required time, space and band
var burndate_layer = mcd.select('BurnDate'); // 
//Map.addLayer(burndate_layer, {}, 'burndate_layer')
//var qa_layer = mcd.select('QA'); 
var yearBegin=2017;
var yearEnd=2018;
var date1=ee.Date.fromYMD(yearBegin,1,1).format('YYYY-MM-dd');
var date2=ee.Date.fromYMD(yearEnd,12,31).format('YYYY-MM-dd');
print(date1,date2)

var collection = mcd.filterDate(date1,date2).filterBounds(roi);
print(collection)

// // identify burned pixels & calculate total burned area

// Function: Identify burnt pixel across image collection
var areaFunction = function(image) {
  var test=ee.Image(image);
  var correctValue = test.select('BurnDate').gt(0).and(test.select('BurnDate').lt(366));
  return correctValue.mask(correctValue);
};

// Function: Convert MCD burnt pixels into forest burnt area
 var burnFunction = function(image) {
  var test=ee.Image(image).mask(NewForestMask);
  var area=test.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()); 
  return area
};

// apply both functions
var burned = collection.map(areaFunction);
var areaburned = burned.map(burnFunction);

// // Aggregate monthly burnt area 
var results = ee.FeatureCollection(
    areaburned.map(function(img) {
var reduced_image_data=img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),geometry: roi,scale: 500, maxPixels: 5e9});
return ee.Feature(null, {'result': reduced_image_data.get('BurnDate')});
    }));

// // export map of all burned pixels (works only for single polygon)
var burned_i = burned.mosaic().multiply(NewForestMask)
var burned_i_all = burned.mosaic()
// var burned_i = burned.mosaic().clip(roi) 

// // Visualize outputs
Map.addLayer(burned_i, {palette:'red'}, 'Forest burned areas')
Map.addLayer(burned_i_all, {palette:'darkred'}, 'all burned areas')

// // calculate burned area (2000-2017)
var burned_i_area=burned_i.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
var burned_m2 = burned_i_area.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),geometry: roi,scale: 500, maxPixels: 5e9});
print('Total forest burned area in 2000-2017 (m2): ',burned_m2) 


// // Export results to .xls (date & area)
print(results.getDownloadURL('csv',['system:index', 'result', '.geo']));

// // export map using a single polygon
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: burned_i,
  description: "burned_area_mask",
  region: roi,
  scale: 30, 
})

// //---------------- end of script -------------------// //

```go
````

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using `export.table.toDrive` instead of `getDownloadURL`:

```
// // export map using a single polygon
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: results,
  description: "test"
})

// // Export results to .xls (date & area)
// print(results.getDownloadURL({format: "csv", filename :"test"}));

// // export map using a single polygon
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: burned_i,
  description: "burned_area_mask",
  region: roi,
  scale: 30, 
})
```